# Firefox Download Manager Tweak Opens numerous download windows

Tags: firefox

When starting Firefox the Download Manager Tweak extension opens numerous download windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Tools menu (press the ALT key), go to Options, click on the *Downloads* menu at the top-right. Under the File/Window tab and under the Download Manager Window legend/fieldset uncheck the "Open the Download Manager after a delay of 0 ms".